# Spring Data with Custom Query and criteria

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data to execute the result list from the database. The result is not the entity type. It's the custom dto. And I want to add the criteria on the query. If the criteria is not null, I want to concat my query with the criteria. Here's my code.

```
public interface JournalReportRepository extends JpaRepository<TxnTransactionLogEntity, String>{
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.bbi.rrs.dto.JournalDto(a.txnReferenceNo, c.accountNo, c.accountName, d.description, a.currencyCode , a.currencyCode, a.txnDate, a.txnAmt, a.smsUserInfo, a.smsUserInfo)  "
        + " FROM TxnTransactionLogEntity a, TxnBalanceEntity b, SmsAccountEntity c, SmsNominalAcodeEntity d WHERE a.smsAccount = c.accountNo AND b.smsAccount = c.accountNo and b.smsNominalAcode = d.nominalAcodeId")
public Page<JournalDto> findJournalReportData(Pageable pageable);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the query based on certain inputs or values, you can use the `Criteria` and `Restriction` classes to build your own query at runtime using the API instead of defining a static query as an annotation. This query for instance can be defined:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;     

public JournalDto findJournalReportData(){
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();            
    CriteriaQuery<JournalDto > query = builder.createQuery(JournalDto.class);         
    Root<JournalDto> dto = query.from(JournalDto.class);
    Root<TxnBalanceEntity> txn = query.from(TxnBalanceEntity.class);
    SetJoin<TxnBalanceEntity, SmsAccountEntity> o = txn.join(SmsAccountEntity.accountNo);

 //..Rest of join statements

}
```